# Spree email doesn't show total and subtotal price, maybe invalid values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

Spree doesn't display subtotal and total price in order confirmation email.
However it displays it correctly on the orders list on the site.

```
 => #<Spree::Order id: 5, number: "R816268161", item_total: #<BigDecimal:c1e72e0,'0.7E4',9(18)>, total: #<BigDecimal:c1e7204,'0.819E4',9(18)>, state: "complete", adjustment_total: #<BigDecimal:c1e7060,'0.119E4',9(18)>, user_id: 1, completed_at: "2013-04-14 13:23:20", bill_address_id: 3, ship_address_id: 4, payment_total: #<BigDecimal:c1e67f0,'0.0',9(18)>, shipping_method_id: 1, shipment_state: "pending", payment_state: "balance_due", email: "my email was here", special_instructions: nil, created_at: "2013-04-14 12:54:32", updated_at: "2013-04-14 13:23:20", currency: "HUF", last_ip_address: "78.92.236.239">
```

It shows at the total a value "BigDecimal" , is this how it should be?

Comment: Short answer, if Spree sets the column as a decimal, then yes that's how it should be when you grab the info from the db.

Comment: This may be a bug if you are not the one creating the confirmation email. Hopefully someone with Spree experience can chime in.

Comment: thx, then the decimal is ok, i created a github issue, just wanted to know if someone here knows the decimal thing, github issue https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/2894